# how to redirect bottom of div tag which is on another page?

Tags: jquery, html

I have created two different HTML pages, **index.html** and **details.html**.

In **index.html**: I have a vertically scrolling div which contains multiple images. When the user clicks on a particular image, it will redirect to **details.html**.

In **details.html**: There is a back button, which will redirect to **index.html**

**Issue**: I want to implement the functionality that when the user presses the back button, it will redirect to the same image which the user has clicked to view. I don't want the time user needing to scroll and continue finding the images where he has last clicked.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Please show the html files for better understanding

Comment: Please add your code for more understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use anchors. You can create an anchor URL like:

```
<a href="index.html#img1">Back Button</a>
```

And place these anchors at `index.html` page in any place:

```
<a name="img1" />
<img src="some-image.jpg" />
```

When user click at the back button, he will be scrolled  to this anchor automatically.
Read more about it.